# ASP.NET - How do you find the process identity?

Tags: asp.net

How do you determine the process identity for ASP.NET? I am getting an UnAthorizedAccessExeption when a user clicks a LinkButton designed to use System.IO to delete a file located in a subfolder of the root folder for a Web Application Project in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the user running the process: [Environment.UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username%28VS.80%29.aspx)

For the person requesting the page: [Page.User.Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx)

**Edit:**  Network Service is the default account used for serving content across the network (e.g. IIS).  See all [built-in accounts](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3648346f-e4f5-474b-86c7-5a86e85fa1ff.mspx?mfr=true).  You'll have to give Network Service access to the folder (giving all your other websites that use this account access as well) or set up another account.

Are you using IIS 6 or 7?

Comment: Nelson, your comment "...or give Network Service access" was what I was really looking for. Avitus offered one way of doing it, yet my shop doesn't use impersonate true. I was already using Windows authentication, and giving Network Service modify rights worked. I'll be back if this doesn't work on the production server. Thanks to all of you for helping me out. As a tumbleweed, I would like to give all of you MAX points. Let me know what I can do to MAX every one appropriately.

Comment: @Berlioz: Just note that in a production environment you may not want to do it this way.  If you give Network Service access to the folder, all the other websites that run as Network Service will also have the access.  Typically you only use Network Service if default permissions/settings are ok, but create a user (it could be a local computer user) for each website you are going to customize.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you want to obtain the process identity within the execution of the ASPX page.  In that case:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and upon inserting your line of code into a label, I got the following to display - "DOMAINNAME\USERNAME". I am obviously using Windows authentication on a Windows network. My next question, please educate me, what is the "NETWORK SERVICE" account?

Comment: There are at least three ways of getting the user: http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vs-net-general/1854/Getting-user-name-Environment-UserName-vs-SystemInformation

Comment: @Berlioz: The Network Service account is an built in local windows account used by processes that host network services. It is the default identity for an IIS application pool.

Answer (score 2):

What you're going to need to do is put an

`<identity impersonate="true" username="x" password="x" />`

tag in your web.config that has rights to delete the file.

Comment: ...or give "Network Service" access, change the user/password in the application pool, use Windows authentication...

Comment: If my solution is in SourceSafe and I debug(F5) on Cassini, will the files be removed from the sub folder, or will SS prevent them from being removed?

Comment: deb=debug?  If you are debugging using Visual Studio's web server (Cassini), then you can't change the application pool (IIS) identity.  What Avitus said should work, otherwise you can give the Network Service account permissions on that folder, or use integrated (Windows) authentication (mostly useful in intranet scenarios)

Comment: In addition, I am also adding files to that same subfolder under the root web app project folder. I am using a input tag with runat server(HtmlInputFile) to do a save to the directory. Again, will SS prevent the files from being added to the subfolder in question?

Comment: @Berlioz:  I believe SourceSafe will mark the files as readonly, so you may need to force the delete or remove the readonly flag before deleting.  How are you planning on keeping the files in sync with SourceSafe?

Comment: No SS won't directly prevent files from being added/deleted.  However, there is the readonly flag as I mentioned and they won't be automatically checked out/in to source control.  What sort of files are you dealing with that need to be modified by your application AND kept in source control?

Answer (score 1):

To find all executing processes u can use `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()`.

For more information on this please check this `URL`:
http://www.itpian.com/Coding/4588-How-to-find-the-active-processes-in-Windows.aspx

Thanks