# Unable to upload file in Network Folder \\NETWORK\PATH\ IIS Returns Access Denied ERROR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

This are some lines of my code:

```
string path = @"\\NETWORK\FOLDER\SUBFOLDER";

if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Comment: The account on which the process runs does not have the required privileges.

Comment: Did you have any process to do this?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857355/asp-net-how-do-you-find-the-process-identity

Comment: Change the user that the app identity runs under

Comment: Time to learn some differences, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Still in search of better answer form experts in #UNCPATH

Comment: What's the identity of application pool you set? Does it have read write permission to network folder.(Better full control permission) Is there any error code or more detailed error message of Denied error? Please show it. Or you can check event viewer  for more message.